# Extract values with condition with xpath and python

Tags: python, html, xpath

This is an extraction of an HTML file from http://www.flashscore.com/hockey/sweden/shl/results/

```
    <td title="Click for match detail!" class="cell_sa score  bold">4:3<br><span class="aet">(3:3)</span></td>
    <td title="Click for match detail!" class="cell_sa score  bold">2:5</td>
```

I would now like to extract the scores after regulation time. 
This means whenever `'span class = "aet"'` is present (after `td class="cell_sa score  bold"`) I need to get the text from `span class = "aet"`. If `span class = "aet"` is not present I would like to extract the text from `td class="cell_sa score  bold"`.

In the above case the desired output (in a list) would be:

```
[3:3,2:5]
```

How could go I go for that with xpath statements in python?

Comment: It looks like that content is created only by Javascript so the problem is not writing an XPath expression to select the values but using Python and XPath on a document tree of that page where Javascript has loaded the data you are looking for.

Comment: Many thanx for the fast reply, Martin. You are right that the content is created by Javascript, however I have already managed to solve that with scrapy & splash. So what I have now is the whole HTML content and I'm only missing the xpath expressions to extract the proper values.

Comment: Btw. what I tried is sel.xpath('//span[@class="aet"]/text()').extract(), but that of course only returns the scores after extra time and I'm missing those where <span class="aet">(3:3)</span> is not present.

Comment: Try the XPath `//td[contains(@class, 'score')]/descendant::text()[last()]` to get a list of those strings (of course you will need to get rid of the `(` and `)` with string processing in Python, XPath 1.0 can't do that in a single expression.

Comment: THIS IS SO AMAZING!!! Works like a charm!!! Thank you very much, Martin!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reach text node of desired tags, obeying conditions you defined by this:

```
(/tr/td[count(./span[@class = 'aet']) > 0]/span[@class = 'aet'] | /tr/td[0 = count(./span[@class = 'aet'])])/text()
```

I supposed `<td>` tags are grouped in a `<tr>` tag.

If you want to strictly just choose `<td>`s having 'cell_sa' and 'score' and 'bold' add `[contains(@class, 'cell_sa')][contains(@class, 'score')][contains(@class, 'bold')]` after each `td`. As below:

```
(/tr/td[contains(@class, 'cell_sa')][contains(@class, 'score')][contains(@class, 'bold')][count(./span[@class = 'aet']) > 0]/span[@class = 'aet'] | /tr/td[contains(@class, 'cell_sa')][contains(@class, 'score')][contains(@class, 'bold')][0 = count(./span[@class = 'aet'])])/text()
```

- As you see I tried to implement `@class` check method order-independently and loose (Just as it is in css selector). You could implement this check as a simple string comparison which results a fragile data consumer

Comment: Thank you very, much, pouyan. That also works perfectly!